# Editing multiple lines of same parameter

Tags: vim, emacs, sublimetext2

I'm working with a large dataset and multiple lines need change on a certain parameter. Something like this for example:

```
funct(35, circle, square, triangle);
funct(42, sphere, cube, prism);
funct(74, disc, rhombus, rectangle);
```

needs to become:

```
funct(35, circle, my_square, other_triangle);
funct(42, sphere, my_cube, other_prism);
funct(74, disc, my_rhombus, other_rectangle);
```

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

An additional vim approach. Visually select all of the lines you would like to change, and then type this:

```
:norm 2Wimy_<C-v><esc>Wiother_
```

Note that `<C-v>` and `<esc>` are `ctrl-v` and `esc`, *not* text. Or, if you want to do this on every line, do this:

```
:%norm 2Wimy_<C-v><esc>Wiother_
```

You could also do this on lines in a certain range. For example, lines 3-100:

```
:3,100norm 2Wimy_<C-v><esc>Wiother_
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll speak about emacs because I just love emacs ! 
to enter commands in the prompt :    `Alt + x`

### For small datasets

You can install the `multiple-cursors` package. It's like the `Ctrl+D` in SublimeText. [Here is the doc](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el).

### For big datasets with some controls

You can use built-in package `query-replace`. It will replace the string/regex you want with another. [Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html).
The advantage of this one is that you can choose if you want to replace or not each occurence.

### For big datasets without control

The built-in packages `replace-string` and `replace-regexp` will replace the pattern of your choice with a string or another pattern. 
[replace-regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html#Regexp-Replace)

[replace-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Unconditional-Replace.html#Unconditional-Replace)

If you just want to rename some variables, `multiples-cursors`, `replace-string` and `query-replace` are fine.
If you want to replace patterns in huge datasets, `replace-regexp` is fun, but nothing's better than a script (bash, js, python ...).

There are amazing books about `sed` and `awk` bash commands ([sed & awk, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do))

Answer (score 0):

With Vim:

```
:%s/\vfunct\(([^,]+,\s*){2}\zs/my_/
```

The `2` above is the number of arguments you want to skip.

The catch: this breaks if some parameters are themselves function calls.  There are plugins that allows you to cope with that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using vim's regex engine:

```
:%s/\v(%(\s*\w+,){PARAMETER_NUMBER})(\s+)(\w+)/\1\2NEW_PREFIX\3
```

Substitute `PARAMETER_NUMBER` with the index (starting from 0) of the parameter you'd like to change and `NEW_PREFIX` with the prefix you'd like to add to it.

For instance, running:

```
:%s/\v(%(\s*\w+,){2})(\s+)(\w+)/\1\2my_\3
```

Changes your example code into:

```
funct(35, circle, my_square, triangle);
funct(42, sphere, my_cube, prism);
funct(74, disc, my_rhombus, rectangle);
```

You can modify this to customize it in other ways by changing the order of the backreferences (the `\1`, `\2` and `\3`) at the end of the command. `\1` refers to the parameters before the one you're changing, `\2` refers to the whitespace just before the parameter you're changing and `\3` to the parameter itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware of `multiple-cursors`, and they look really cool, but I've been to lazy to learn them.  Here's a solution using only Emacs built ins.

```
(defun align-regexp-comma (beginning end)
  "Align columns using comma as a delimiter."
  (interactive "*r")
  (align-regexp beginning end
                ",\\(\\s-*\\)" 1 1 t))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-<return>") 'cua-rectangle-mark-mode)
```

Then select the region you of interest, do `M-x align-regexp-comma`, which should align the arguments, then you can use `C-<return>` to start the rectangle mark, which lets you edit several lines at once.  If you then want to remove the aligning spaces, use `query-regexp-replace` (`M-%`) with ", +" -> ", ".